# RAPHAEL GWT CANVAS ISSUE

Tags: gwt, raphael

I am working on RAPHAEL-GWT and am able to generate the raphael diagram. My problem is that it is exceeding the specified width and height of the Raphael GWT canvas.

How can i add a scroll-bar to the Raphael GWT canvas to accommodate the entire diagram within the given width and height of the Raphael canvas?

Are there any other ways or workarounds to handle the above case?

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

One simple idea is 
Raphael container() in which you draw your graphic elements, should have maximum height on browser. And an outer div fixed height with overflow:auto in CSS.